# Sitecore SXA Carousel Component not working in IE 11

Tags: sxa

We are working with Sitecore 9.0.2(PAAS) and SXA 1.7.1 and we are using one of the rendering variants for the Carousel Component and we are facing some serious issues with IE 11.

The issue is that the SXA “Carousel” component does not switch to the next slide automatically or manually on click of the next icon in IE 11.

Has someone faced this issue before? Is this an issue with Sitecore SXA?

Cheers

Comment: Hi Alivor - I have not encountered this issue specifically, but can you try using your browser development tools and look at the console to see if any errors are being surfaced? Also doesn't hurt to inspect the elements on the page to make sure they are being rendered as expected. Report back with what you find, please. Best Wishes. justin

Answer (score 1):

We found that there is issue with function Number.paresInt() it is native to ES6 , it is not supported in IE & Safari.

So we changed the function to polyfill  so avoid that issue. This function works across all browsers

Comment: awesome. thanks for posting the answer so others can resolve this issue if they come across it. cheers.